# Availability of logic lectures online

Tags: logic, soft-question, online-resources, higher-order-logic

I am currently reading Logic an Structure by Dirk van Dalen (2008).

However, I am missing some basics I try to find related lectures on online / on youtube. I frequently watch [MIT](http://youtube.com/user/MIT), [Stanford](http://youtube.com/user/StanfordUniversity), and [University of Nottinham](http://youtube.com/user/NottmUniversity) lectures on youtube.

However, I have a hard time to find lectures on topics like predicate logic, high order logic, and  intuitionistic logic. Does anyone happen to have pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a link with various lectures on logic in general. I hope some of them are related to what you're looking for: http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/Logic/

Comment: thanks very much for the link. just what I was looking for ;-)

Answer (score 0):

MIT is certainly good, I don't know what your level is but I personally prefer summer school courses: they are shorter and more condensed, so you may learn more in shorter periods of time. Plus they are addressed to a general audience.

When you search on google, try to add key words like "summer school", "winter school". Take a look at this lecture by [Alwen Tiu](http://videolectures.net/ssll09_tiu_intlo/), for instance.

More generally, I think that for very basic notions, books are better.

Answer (score -1):

You can try "carneades" *youtube.com* channel and "trev tutor". Both of them have large playlists covering basic logic and set theory.

"carneades" is a philosophy channel, but has great insights.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz0n_SjOttTcjHsuebLrl0fjab5fdToui

The last ten videos of this one has predicate calculus.